# Cheese (Camera) is not working in Ubuntu 20.04 on my Corei7 11th Gen(Lenovo Thinkbook)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, camera, troubleshooting

My camera was working properly yesterday, but all of sudden it stopped working next day. I can only see the black screen as below:

[image]

**My system details are:**

[image]

**I've tried all the other solutions like killing the processes but it didn't work.**
[image]

**When I run the command of cheese:**
[image]

Comment: maybe the camera hardware failed

Comment: I would hazard a guess and say you have not got the device driver kernel modules loaded, since there is no /dev/video*.

Comment: If I run the camera, it shows black screen. In the meanwhile, If I run `lsof /dev/video0`, I get the following output.

`COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME`
`cheese  11278 xgrid   26u   CHR   81,0      0t0  500 /dev/video0`
`cheese  11278 xgrid   37u   CHR   81,0      0t0  500 /dev/video0`

Comment: `xgrid@faheem-thinkbook:~$ ls -ltrh /dev/video*`
`crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 Dec 14 21:36 /dev/video1`
`crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Dec 14 21:36 /dev/video0`
`xgrid@faheem-thinkbook:~$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices`
`Integrated Camera: Integrated C (usb-0000:00:14.0-7):`
 `/dev/video0`
 `/dev/video1`

`xgrid@faheem-thinkbook:~$ cheese`
`../src/intel/isl/isl.c:2023: FINISHME: ../src/intel/isl/isl.c:isl_surf_supports_ccs: CCS` `for 3D textures is disabled, but a workaround is available.`

Comment: I got the same issue, please check the stupid answer here. It solved my problem :) https://superuser.com/questions/968727/ubuntu-turns-on-webcam-but-black-screen-in-cheese